# angular.isUndefined & angular.equals in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I just began to try to migrate from angular 1 to 2, actually from ionic 1 to 2, and one of my first compilation error is that angular.isUndefined and angular.equals aren't resolved.

How should I fix that, any tips?

```
namespace Utils {

export class Comparator {

    static isEmpty(obj:any):boolean {
        return obj == null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
    }

    static isNumberNullOrZero(obj:number):boolean {
        return obj == null || obj === 0;
    }

    static equals(obj1:any, obj2:any):boolean {
        return angular.equals(obj1, obj2); // <== here angular unresolved
    }

    static isStringEmpty(str:string):boolean {
        return !str || 0 === str.length;
    }

    static isStringBlank(str:string):boolean {
        return !str || /^\s*$/.test(str);
    }

    static isBiggerThanZero(num:number):boolean {
        return num != null && !angular.isUndefined(num) && num > 0; // <== here angular unresolved
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can simply replace `angular.isUndefined(num)` with `num === undefined`.

Object equality is a bit trickier. There are libraries that include such functionality, e.g. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I corrected the undefined as you said. For the equality check I choose underscore instead of Lo-dash because underscore seems to be more performant.

Answer (score 2):

You probably has already fixed it, but **if you were wondering why those methods are not in angular2**, here is why.

As you may know, angular team prefixed object names provided by the framework with $. That was a naming convention in angular1 to avoid collisions with the application code.

It turned out that they also needed to implement some methods like equals to ignore those prefixed properties. And that is one of the things that angular.equals does. If you compare objects using angular.equals those prefixes are ignored.

```
angular.equals({a: 1}, {a: 1}) === true
angular.equals({a: 1}, {a: 1, $a: 2}) === true
```

Find more in this [post](http://www.codelord.net/2016/11/02/what-angular-dot-equals-and-angular-dot-tojson-are-for/)

Answer (score 0):

replace `angular.isUndefined` with `isUndefined`, and add the function below for your code

```js

```
function isUndefined(o) {
    return typeof o === 'undefined';
}
```

```

Comment: In this case you can just use `o === undefined` since there's no chance that the variable `o` is not available in this scope as it's already an argument to the function. It still may contain the value `undefined`

Answer (score -4):

Angular2 dont have isUndefined

You can simply replace  angular.isUndefined(num) by

```
if (!num) {
}
```

Comment: What if num === 0?